# PhoneGap "connecting to device"?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I recently installed the phonegap app to my phone and desktop. I did the sample app from the tutorial provided on the website http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/desktop/ everything worked find and synced to my phone just fine. However when I try to create a new project it just says on my mobile device "connecting to device" and nothing happens. I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Or is the PhoneGap Developer app just getting stuck at the "connecting to device" message?

Comment: The phone gap app was stuck. What I wound up doing was using the sample and altering but for some reason I think the problem lies in the way I setup the ID. Is that a factor in the app working or not? Thank You for your help!

Comment: I fiexed this problem disabling the Windows firewall. It was preventing the connection